# Iterating over ListView Items win32 api

Tags: c++, listview, winapi, listviewitem, win32gui

I currently have a handle to my Listview via `HWND lv = GetDlgItem(hDlg, MY_LISTVIEW)`

and its currently populated with items using `ListView_SetItemText();`
I want to update each item in that listview based on data that has been updated externally.  How would I iterate over each listview item given my handle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListViews use a 0-based index to identify items, so to iterate over the items it's simply a matter of getting the total and then running a loop that counts from 0. For example,

```
int iNumItems = ListView_GetItemCount(lv);
for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < iNumItems; ++iIndex)
{
    // update this item
    ListView_SetItemText(lv, iIndex, 0, ...);
}
```

Comment: Ah this is what I was looking for!  scouring online didnt give me clear answers thank you!  What function would I call to refresh the window after im done update the items?

Comment: They'll refresh automatically as you update them. You can actually disable this using `SetWindowRedraw()` if you want (turn off redraw, update all the items, then turn it back on again) which can sometimes look nicer.

Comment: @Chris "*scouring online didnt give me clear answers*" - when all else fails, [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/bumper-list-view-list-view-control-overviews)! In particular, the section on [List-View Items and Subitems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/list-view-controls-overview#list-view-items-and-subitems).